# using regex for lines in a file

Tags: python, regex, file

I have text file which should change like this:

> Go through the lines and If you see **print var[number or string]** change it to **print ( var[number or string])**

For input:

> a = [1,2,3]
>
> print a[1]

output must be:

> a = [1,2,3]
>
> print(a[1])

I tried this:

```
import re
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
     data = f.read()

newline = re.sub(r"^print\s(.+)", r"print(\1)", data)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
f.write(newline)
```

It only works when print is in first line. How should I check all the lines and change them?

Comment: You are only reading the first line of the file. You need to `readLines()` and then iterate each line in the `with open()` part of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `M` flag to match the start of a line with `^` instead of the start of the text.

```
re.sub("^a", "c", "abba\nabba", flags=re.M)
'cbba\ncbba'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the indentations. The only line inside the `with` is the line reading a line of text and you need to include the lines where you change the text and the one writing to the new file.

Try this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('file-2.txt', 'w') as fout:
        data = f.read()
        newline = re.sub(r"^print\s(.+)", r"print(\1)", data)
        fout.write(newline)
```

Comment: Didn't realize the OP was saving the result in the same file!. Edited my answer to save the result in another file.